# Any way to hard reset a HDC A9100?

Tags: hard-reset

I need to hard reset my HDC  A9100 any way I can. Please, does anyone know how?

To clarify: 
I need to overcome a forgotten screen lock, and the documentation provides no helpful information (it's here: http://www.swedishphones.com/uploads/7/4/6/3/7463877/hdc_a9100__manual.pdf)

A few attempts at the 'hold the volume buttons' etc while it powers on have been unsuccessful.

I do know the right username/pass combination for the "forgotten your..." screen, but it doesn't appear to work.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Why do you need to hard reset? Surely your HDC A9100 has some booklet or documentation on this? If not, please clarify what Android version you're running. It could be a factory reset that is needed?

Comment: edited to include more info.

Comment: Still looks like you rather mean a factory-reset. Please hold your mouse-pointer over the tag to see what hard-reset stands for: nothing but a "forced reboot", which is unlikely to solve your issue. I'd rather re-phrase your question, as it is what we call a [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/): You probably don't want to know how to do a hard-reset, but how to overcome your screen-lock problem, correct?

Comment: See also: [Q: Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/16575), which has a lot of solutions to get around the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the standard Android hard reset? I heard this works for all Android phones.

- turn it off (if you cannot shoot it down, remove the battery).
- hold both volume-buttons **and** the home-button **and then** hold the  power button. about 5 seconds

use this at your **own risk!** You will lose all your installed data and get a clear reset to shipping settings, if it works.

there are some [videos about it on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PT2CwF_GW0A).

Comment: Is this standard across the board? Clearly the OP has not provided enough clues.

Comment: I added some more info, but I've tried this and it didn't seem to work...